# Mapping an ID number to a class

Tags: c++, class

I'm setting up a system where I can instantiate classes on the fly based on some information read in from a file.  So, this has to be done on runtime.  The classes in question are polymorphic and all inherit from the `CBaseTheoryEnt` class.  What I want to do is associate an ID number with each class (with an unordered map for example).  Essentially, my management class is going to look at a series of these ID numbers read in from the input file and then instantiate the appropriate classes.  What would be an ideal and efficient way of associating the classes with the ID and then instantiating them based on the input?

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of using RTTI (e.g. `typeid`) for this. You will regret it when you find you can't read your saved game info after recompiling.

Comment: @sehe typeid is what I was afraid of running into! Haha

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to use [Boost.Serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for this? If you're only ever going to save/load this data from a file, then it's more than likely the best solution. It even allows versioning and non-intrusive mechanics.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I actually haven't familiarized myself that much with Boost for some odd reason.  If you could post an example, that would be great! :)

Comment: @MGZero: [the documentation for Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) has a list of samples, introduced with proper explanation. It's kind of hard to tell _what_ you will be needing without knowing more about your type hierarchy. I recommend you look for yourself. No boost library has ever cost me more than a day's worth of fiddling to get started. (Well, except the more abstract ones, like Boost MPL, Boost Proto and perhaps Boost Spirit; they did require some real learning curve IMO)

Comment: @sehe Sounds good, I'll get reading then!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a template function to instantiate the subclasses of `CBaseTheoryEnt`:

```
template<typename T>
CBaseTheoryEnt* instantiator() {
    return new T;
}
```

Then have a `hash_map` or array of these functions for each class that is derived from `CBaseTheoryEnt` and have the key for that class be associated with the instantiator for it. Then when you index the array or map, you get a function which, when called, will return a pointer to an instance of the appropriate class.

For instance, if you had classes A, B, and C, and the id for A was 0, for B was 1, and C was 2, you'd have:

```
typedef CBaseTheoryEnt* (*instantiator_ptr)();
instantiator_ptr classes[] = {
    &instantiator<A>,
    &instantiator<B>,
    &instantiator<C>
};
```

Then use it like

```
int idx = get_class_id();

CBaseTheoryEnt* inst = classes[idx]();
```

Comment: Since the user didn't ask for a C++11 solution, perhaps you could remove the C++11 bits, so we could see what the type of `classes` is.

Comment: this looks a bit like what Boost Serialization uses (of course much more complicated - sic) to register serializable types.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `classes` would actually be of type `std::initializer_list<CBaseTheoryEnt*()>`. Mmm.

Comment: I like this.  Quick, clean and to the point.  I'll wait a little bit on accepting the answer to see what others think.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @sehe: No it would not, since the user asked for C++, not C++11. It would be a compiler error, which is why I asked for a more portable answer.

Comment: @MGZero and if your indices are not integers (like strings or something) you can use one of the `map`s instead.

Comment: @NicolBolas: haha ever the pedantic :) Now, I'm inclined to think that C++11 is in fact C++ too (_sic_). Thus, seeing that the code made no sense in C++03, I instead assumed that it was in fact C++0x or later. Unsurprisingly, my comment is also correct in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give too many specifics, so here's a fairly general approach using a `map` that might apply:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual int ID() const = 0;
  // ...
};

typedef Base * (*create_fp)();
typedef std::map<int, create_fp> create_map;

class DerivedA : public Base { /* ... */ };
class DerivedB : public Base { /* ... */ };
class DerivedC : public Base { /* ... */ };

namespace BaseCreators
{
  DerivedA * makeA() { /* ... */ }
  DerivedB * makeA() { /* ... */ }
  DerivedC * makeA() { /* ... */ }
}

const create_map creators {
  { 1, BaseCreators::makeA },
  { 2, BaseCreators::makeB },
  { 3, BaseCreators::makeC }
};

int main()
{
  int a = get_id_from_user();
  create_fp cr = creators.find(a)->second; // or check for existence first
  Base * b = cr();
}
```

(If you don't have C++11, you'll have to make the `creators` map non-constant and populate it manually.)